# Preserve file white spaces while reading file using jsch in java EE

Tags: java, jsch, java-ee-7

I'm trying to read a file from a remote server using Jsch and print the contents in html file, It works fine but the file white spaces don't appear correctly in the Servlet.

For example, the contents of the file are formatted as the below :

Filesystem              Free%            Used%            
/home                    35%               65%
/usr                        80%               20%

But instead, I have them look like the below in the Servlet :

Filesystem Free% Used% /home 35% 65% /usr 80% 20%

And here is the code that I'm using :

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet NewServlet</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        
        try {
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession("myuser", "192.168.1.25", 22);
            session.setPassword("myuser");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            ChannelSftp channel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            
            InputStream stream = channel.get("/home/myuser/log.txt");
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    out.println(line);
                }

            } catch (IOException io) {
                System.out.println("Exception occurred during reading file from SFTP server due to " + io.getMessage());
                io.getMessage();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception occurred during reading file from SFTP server due to " + e.getMessage());
                e.getMessage();

            }

            
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to pot the content into a <pre> tag

Comment: Multiple whitespaces will be displayed as only one whitespace (collapsing). But you can convert it to non-breaking space for example, using `string.replace(" ", "&nbsp;")`, or to any other non-collapsing whitespace chars. For more spaces check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Comment: @Jens I have tried to put <pre> tag and it worked like charm! Thanks a lot.

Comment: HI @MichaelFikry please don't post images of code, command output, or error messages as images: [Why Should I Not Upload Images of Code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Please edit your question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Jens Thank you for the answer
The issue was solved after adding the <pre> tag before the content